# Can Python 3.x enforce that a method param is a specific class instance/object? (ala PHP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, type-hinting

Python, being dynamically typed, has no provision for type-hinting on method parameters. However, PHP, also being dynamically typed, *does* have a provision for type-hinting that a method parameter is at least an instance of a class (or that it is an instance of a class that inherits from a defined class).

```php
public class Foo()
{
    public function __construct($qux, ...)
    {
        $this->qux = qux;
        ...
    }
}

public class Bar() 
{
    // "Type Hinting" done here enforcing 
    // that $baz is an instance of Foo
    public function __construct(Foo $baz, ...)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a similar way of enforcing that a method param is a specific instance in Python?

If not, is the proper convention to simply assert?

```python
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, qux=None, ...):
        self.qux = qux
        ...


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, baz=None, ...):
        # "Type Hinting" done here as `assert`, and
        # requires catch of AssertionError elsewhere
        assert isinstance(baz, Foo)

        self.baz = baz
        ...
```

If this is style of using `assert` is incorrect/inelegant/"*not pythonic*", what should I do instead?

Comment: I'd raise a `TypeError` exception, rather but your code looks good... Although be aware that `isinstance` will be `True` for all the child instances of `Foo` (you can enforce just `Foo` by doing `type(baz) == Foo` (no parenthesis on `Foo`)

Comment: Actually the Pythonic thing to do is use "duck typing"; if the value works, let it, regardless of whether it's the type you expect. That's why we talk of file like objects, sequences, etc - they're expected protocols, what Java would call interfaces, although they're not specified in the language. There is one type constraint built into the language, though; `self` on methods is type checked.

Comment: Today I would recommend using MyPy to check type annotations.

Answer (score 4):

Not out of the box. You can, however, combine [parameter annotations](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) with function decorators to almost effortlessly write your own.

Keep in mind, however, that the whole idea of [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128123/how-to-design-code-in-python/22128361#22128361) is to avoid this kind of logic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a strong convention in Python to embrace the [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) idiom, which in this case would mean that you would call the appropriate attributes from the `baz` object without explicitly checking its type. This has many benefits, including  better support for polymorphism and arguably more readable / less verbose code.

If you tried to access an attribute which the object does not support, a `AttributeError` exception is raised. Therefore you could place this inside a `try/except` block and catch any `AttributeError` when appropriate - this is characteristic of another Python idiom called ['Easier to ask forgiveness than permission'](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

```
try:
    baz.foo
except AttributeError:
    # handle the exception
```

Some other questions that cover this topic

- [Is it Pythonic to check function argument types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950386/is-it-pythonic-to-check-function-argument-types?rq=1)
- [Type checking of arguments Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734368/type-checking-of-arguments-python)
- [Productivity gains of duck typing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122205/what-is-the-supposed-productivity-gain-of-dynamic-typing)
- [What is the EAFP principle in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)